# В одномерном массиве размерности n найти МАКСИМАЛЬНОЕ значение из

Tags: c++, c

МАКСИМАЛЬНОЕ значение из ( максимального значения первых 3 положительных чисел массива , минимальное значение из 2 последних элементов массива ). Вывести массив подкрасив подходящие по условию эл-ты (т.е. первые 3 положит эл-та и последние 2 четных эл-та ПыСы в зеленый цвет и красный соответственно). Проблема в том , что я не могу вывести и использовать последние 2 четных эл-та. Эл-ты не на последних 2 четных позициях а именно 2 последних четных эл-та. 
(в задачке надо ещё 2 условия реализовать не обращайте внимания, всё в case 1 )

вот мой код

---

---

```
const int n = 10;

// Наш массив заданный вручную.
int a[n];

// Переменная для меню.
int choice;

// Переменные хранящие размер наших вспомогательных массивов.
int count1=0,count2=0;

int s =0;
int k = 0;

 // Для хранения первых 3х положительных значений массива и последних двух чётных чисел массива сответственно.
int x[count1],y[count2];
int max1,max2,min1,i,m=0;

int AverageValue = 0, sum = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("a[%d]=",i);
    scanf("%i",&a[i]);
}

printf("\nEnter \n1) max(max(first 3), min(last 2 even)."); 

printf("\n2) Average even(3 elements before average element of array.");

printf("\n3) Elements who mod 5 == 0 replace to 15.");

printf("\n Enter your choice = ");

scanf("%i",&choice);


switch(choice)
{
case 1:
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if( m < 3)
        {
            if (a[i] > 0)
            {
                SetColor(2);
                printf("\t%i",a[i]);
                x[count1++] = a[i];
                m++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                SetColor(15);
                printf("\t%i",a[i]);
                continue;
            }
        }

        if ((a[i] % 2 == 0)&&(k < 2))
        {
            SetColor(4);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);

            // Записываем нужные эл-ты в массив для последущего нахождения 
            // максимального значения.
            y[count2++] = a[i];
            k++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            SetColor(15);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
            continue;
        }

    }
    SetColor(15);

    max1 = x[0];
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
    {
        max1 = x[i] > max1 ? x[i] : max1;
    }

    min1 = y[0];
    for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        min1 = y[i] < min1 ? y[i] : min1;
    }

    max2 = max1 > min1 ? max1 : min1;
    printf("\nMax Value from %i and %i is %i",max1,min1,max2);

    break;

case 2:

    m = 0;
    i = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(( a[i] % 2 == 0)&&(k<3)&&(i < n/2))
        {
            SetColor(2);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
            sum += a[i];
            // M хранит кол-во чётных элементов до середины массива.
            m++;
        }
        else
        {
            SetColor(15);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
        }

    }

    AverageValue = sum / m;
    printf("\nAverageValue = %i",AverageValue);

    break;
case 3:

    for ( i =0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ( a[i] % 5 == 0)
        {
            a[i] = 15;
            SetColor(2);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
            // S хранит кол-во элементов делящихся на 5.
            s++;
        }
        else
        {
            SetColor(15);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);

        }

    }

    break;
default:
    printf("enter 1 or 2 or 3!");
    goto def;
}
```

Comment: наверное надо бегать с конца массива чтоб найти 2 последних элемента ,но также надо найти и первые 3 и вывести всё в строчку, и подсветить... вот такие пироги.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Размер массива
const int n = 10;

// Наш массив заданный вручную.
int a[n];

// Переменная для меню.
int choice;

// Переменные хранящие размер наших вспомогательных массивов.
int count1=0,count2=0,count3=0;

int s =0;
int k = 0;

 // Для хранения первых 3х положительных значений массива и последних двух чётных чисел массива сответственно.
int x[count1],y[count2],z[count3];
int max1,max2,min1,i,m=0;

int AverageValue = 0, sum = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("a[%d]=",i);
    scanf("%i",&a[i]);
}
```

def:
    printf("\n Enter \n 1) max(max(first 3), min(last 2 even). \n 2) Average even(3 elements before average element of array. \n 3) Elements who are devidet into 5 replace to 15.))\n Enter your choice = ");
    scanf("%i",&choice);

```
switch(choice)
{
case 1:
    for ( i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                z[count3++]=i;

            }
            continue;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if( m < 3)
        {
            if (a[i] > 0)
            {
                SetColor(2);
                printf("\t%i",a[i]);
                x[count1++] = a[i];
                m++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                SetColor(15);
                printf("\t%i",a[i]);
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (( i == z[0] )||( i == z[1] ) )
        {
            SetColor(4);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
            // Записываем нужные эл-ты в массив для последущего нахождения максимального значения.
            y[count2++] = a[i];
            k++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            SetColor(15);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
            continue;
        }

    }
    SetColor(15);

    max1 = x[0];
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
    {
        max1 = x[i] > max1 ? x[i] : max1;
    }

    min1 = y[0];
    for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        min1 = y[i] < min1 ? y[i] : min1;
    }

    max2 = max1 > min1 ? max1 : min1;
    printf("\nMax Value from %i and %i is %i",max1,min1,max2);

    break;

case 2:

    m = 0;
    i = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(( a[i] % 2 == 0)&&(k<3)&&(i < n/2))
        {
            SetColor(2);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
            sum += a[i];
            // M хранит кол-во чётных элементов до середины массива.
            m++;
        }
        else
        {
            SetColor(15);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
        }

    }

    AverageValue = sum / m;
    printf("\nAverageValue = %i",AverageValue);

    break;
case 3:

    for ( i =0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ( a[i] % 5 == 0)
        {
            a[i] = 15;
            SetColor(2);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);
            // S хранит кол-во элементов делящихся на 5.
            s++;
        }
        else
        {
            SetColor(15);
            printf("\t%i",a[i]);

        }

    }

    break;
default:
    printf("enter 1 or 2 or 3!");
    goto def;
}
```